# How to use multiple ampersands for an anchor element?

Tags: css, sass

scss

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  &:active {
  color: $color-secondary;
  }
  &:visited {
    color: $color-primary;
  }
  &:hover {
  color: $color-accent;
  }
}
```

css

```
a:active {
  color: #E4E4E4;
}


a:visited {
  color: #333;
}


a:hover {
  color: #6DB48B;
}
```

The compiled css only takes the last property into consideration.
How do I use multiple ampersands for an anchor element?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Can you rephrase, better just show in code, what did you try? what was the result? and what is the result you expect?

Comment: What you are showing is correct.  From your output I see you are missing the declaration `a { text-decoration: none; }` in your results.  Is this the whole output?  Could that be somewhere else in the file?

Comment: `a { text-decoration: none; }` is located in the output above the output css I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:active` styles fail to show because they get overridden by the styles that appear lower down in your Sass. To fix this, reorder your Sass in this order:

1. `:visited`
2. `:hover`
3. `:active`